# Can Mike the Cowboy survive Part 1 Chapter 2?

Tags: max-payne-2

When you come to Vlad's help in Part I, Chapter 2, you will meet up with Tommy the Cowboy.

In my past playthroughs this guy always died at least when the final assault took place just before getting to Vlad.

So I was wondering:

1. Is it possible for Tommy the Cowboy to survive?
2. If it is possible, is this recognized by the game either by character reaction or bonus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, he can. He will walk up to Vladimir Lem if you succeed. But Vlad will not notice this and still only say "my hero".
2. No bonus, but you will meet him a second time. This time as an enemy and he will taunt you through the microphone.

So in retrospect, best course of action is shooting him in the back to get his Kalashnikov ;-)

Comment: No that is not good because i have saved him